# How to fix screen overlap and top left zoom of HD external monitors while using 4k primary Linux Ubuntu 20?

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, multiple-monitors, 20.04, display

I have two external monitors connected to my laptop, and am running Linux Ubuntu 20. I am having an issue with my displays. The external monitors in reality are zoomed in on the upper left side, and are so "big" that the display of the monitor is overlapping. Interesting enough, when I screen shot the setup, the displays appear how I want them to appear. I took a picture to show what is actually occurring.

Here is the screen shot taken:
[image: screenshot]

Here what it actually looks like:
[image: realcapture]

The top two monitors are 1920 x 1080, and the bottom primary is 3840 x 2160.

Does anyone know what is going on here and how to fix it?

Thank you for your time.

Ps. Original post did not include images; 10 reputation points needed to post images.

Comment: Upvoted. I think what you need might be controlled by `xrandr`'s options for `--fb` and `--panning`.

Comment: Thank you @WinEunuuchs2Unix. I looked a post about  `--fb` and `--panning`, and I'm still not quite sure how to fix what I'm seeing. Do you know why it zooms in on the upper left of the HD monitors like that?

Comment: I also have two 1920x1080 externals and a 3840x2160 internal. From time to time the top left 1920x1080 monitor is zoomed in an pans the entire desktop. I had to create a function to reset the displays and disabled the panning. I need to call the script once a month or so for some reason.

Comment: Is it a .sh? Any way you could post that? I think my reputation is too low to up-vote you, sorry. Although, given that I'm converting from MacOS to LUbuntu, someday I should have the reputation and would come back to up-vote this!

Comment: It's a function in `~/.bashrc` file but I'll convert it to a `.sh` file format in a few minutes. Don't worry about upvoting. But you can accept the answer if it works for you. That gives you 2 points and me 10. I don't really need anymore points though :)

Comment: Answer posted. Note earlier comment was wrong. I have one external 1920x1080, one external 3840x2160 and an internal 1920x1080. It was only the external 1920x1080 that would resort to panning every now and then.

Comment: I appreciate your help man. My quick fix for this has been to turn off "fractional scaling" and just make my 4k be at 1920 x 1080 and scale it all at 100%. It'll just be this way for now I guess

Comment: I also have fractional scaling turned off but a zoom factor of 1.38 set using tweak tool. Then I set font size a little larger in some apps and have Firefox zoomed at 110%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your `~/.bashrc` file to be able to call `xreset` from the command line:

```bash
xreset () {

    # Reset xrandr to normal, first use: xrandr | grep " connected "
    # HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
    # eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
    # DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
    xrandr --output HDMI-0  --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0       --rotate normal \
           --fb 1920x1080   --panning 1920x1080 \
           --output eDP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x2160 --rotate normal \
           --primary \
           --output DP-1-1  --mode 3840x2160 --pos 1920x0    --rotate normal

    # --panning option added because HDMI-0 was mirroring all other monitors
    # and "panning" back and forth. --fb option added next day.

} # xreset
```

Or if you prefer to create an `.sh` file use this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

    # Reset xrandr to normal, first use: xrandr | grep " connected "
    # HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
    # eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
    # DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
    xrandr --output HDMI-0  --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0       --rotate normal \
           --fb 1920x1080   --panning 1920x1080 \
           --output eDP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x2160 --rotate normal \
           --primary \
           --output DP-1-1  --mode 3840x2160 --pos 1920x0    --rotate normal

    # --panning option added because HDMI-0 was mirroring all other monitors
    # and "panning" back and forth. --fb option added next day.
```

Save to a file and mark it executable with `chmod a+x filename`

First you need to discover you monitor properties with:

```bash
xrandr | grep " connected"
```

Then using reported properties change the `xreset` function accordingly.

Comment: I cant get it right. I think it has something to do with being updated on 20.04 all the way

Comment: @GeneralCode Not sure what you mean by "updated all the way". Do you mean you used to be running 18.04 and upgraded it?

Comment: No I installed this boot from 20.04 today. Then once I installed it things were working properly with the "fractional scaling" however, the mouse was flickering real bad on the 4k monitor, so I updated everything. Then once I updated I got this issue